# Xcode 4.5: Broken indentation when using with preprocessor directives

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, preprocessor

I'm currently using Xcode 4.5.2. There's something weird with indentation when using preprocessor directives (the conditional inclusions). Here's what my code looks like:

```
-(void)someMethod{
#if defined (TEST_A) || defined (TEST_B)
    if (![self TESTmethod]) {
        //do sth   
#else
    if (![self method]) {  
#endif
        //do sth
    }
}
```

When I hit 'return/enter' , the cursor move right-side with some extra space as shown in picture below:
[image]

If I remove preprocessor directives it will indent correctly, but I want to use preprocessor directives. Any solution? Thanks

Comment: when I experiment the same behavior I close and reopen Xcode and then it works as expected

Comment: does not work for me. Even restarting Mac won't solve this

Comment: It worked for me, without any thing such!!!

Comment: I've voted to reopen this. SO isn't just for programming questions, but the tools used for programming: From the [FAQ] `but if your question generally covers … software tools commonly used by programmers … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!`

Comment: Voted to reopen, valid question - Suggest you raise a bug with apple. It looks like the indenter is counting {} pairs and getting confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve it by altering the code:

```
-(void)someMethod{
#if defined (TEST_A) || defined (TEST_B)
    if (![self TESTmethod]) {
        //do sth 
    }  
#else
    if (![self method]) {  
        //do sth
    }
#endif
}
```

This solve the indentation problem. Weird